# how do i go about template matching these blurry images?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Template

[image: template]

Image to be matched

[image: image to be matched]

I tried template matching but the results were mostly false and then i dived into feature matching using SURF,SIFT,ORB. None of them gave good results. below is one of the result

Sift matching with Flann result

[image: Sift matching with Flann result]

Need someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reverse video your template...

Instead of having a white glove on a black background, make it a black glove on a white background.
With a 1 channel image, in python you can do :
img = 255 -img.

Comment: reverse video ? I have no idea what you're talking about. It's not related to a video.